# Matlab, find the intersection of two abitrary region

Tags: image-processing, morphological-analysis, mathematical-morphology

I have two binary image, A and B ( A and B are same size but have different object). There are many regions in each image. Now I want to find the neighbor of any regions in A. I use imdilate - dilation function in matlab. Because after dilation the regions of A will be increase so this may be connected with a region in B. I will add the region of B to A and continue to do it. I will stop when we can't add any region of B to A.

I don't know how to code this ? can you help me. thank you so much ? will it take a lot of time to calculate?

Answer (score 2):

The operation in binary is called a geodesic reconstruction of set B under the dilate of set A. One can also perform this with the Erode of the complement of set A. You can perform this with [imreconstruct](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/images/ref/imreconstruct.html) in matlab. This helps extract certain components in set B by choosing the set A. Here the set A is called the marker and set B is called the mask. The calculation is in nearly linear time like the component labeling operation.